# Is it possible to recover or create a index.php for a typo3 installation

Tags: wordpress, indexing, typo3

We have several websites running on our web space.
The root directory is occupied with a Typo3 website.
I wanted to include a new Wordpress installation into a subdirectory.
Unfortunately i put the wordpress site also into the root directory and overwrote the index.php file.

The typo3 site is not accessible any more via the URL. However from the admin interface everything seems to be fine. I do not have access to this IF at the moment (its a bit tricky) which is why i suggest only the index file is destroyed.

Is there a way to create a new index file for this specific installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (if it wasn't modified) use the index.php that was delivered with the TYPO3 core version you are using. You can download most versions of the TYPO3 core (since TYPO3 4.2 or so) at http://get.typo3.org/

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I downloaded the matching version and simply replaced the index.php. Luckily it wasn't modified and  the website is working again.

Comment: You just saved my life mate. Thank you so much. Such a simple solution for a problem I was trying to solve for 2 hours now. Cheers